# CMake Functions work with 'catkin_make' but fail with 'catkin build

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two catkin packages. One package will be called 'function_maker' and the other is 'function_user'. Here are my two CMakeLists.txt:

function_maker CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(function_maker)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11 -g)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_package()

function(test_func arg)
    message("Function Called")
endfunction()
```

function_user CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(function_user)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11 -g)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
        function_maker
)

catkin_package()

test_func()
```

When I use 'catkin_make' to build my workspace, everything works as expected and during the build process I see a message that says "Function Called".

However, when I use 'catkin build' to build my workspace, I get the following error message:

```
Unknown CMake command "test_func".
```

Why is there a difference between 'catkin_make' and 'catkin build'? How can I make this work with both build tools?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320815/cmake-functions-work-with-%27catkin_make%27-but-fail-with-%27catkin-build/) by [Spencer Fishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40813/spencer-fishman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-04-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-10**:\

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> ```

```
    COMPONENETS
        function_maker
```

is this a copy-pasta? `COMPONENETS` is not a recognised argument to `find_package(..)`.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-10**:
Please read https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html which describes the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most likely reason is that `catkin_make` coalesces all projects (ie: ROS packages) into a single build (equivalent to calling `add_subdirectory(..)`) whereas `catkin_tools` (which supplies the `catkin` command) builds all packages in isolation.

(Edit: including @Dirk Thomas' comment) Refer to [Migrating from catkin_make](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) in the `catkin_tools` documentation for more information on the differences between `catkin_make` and `catkin_tools`.

> When I use 'catkin_make' to build my workspace, everything works as expected and during the build process I see a message that says "Function Called".
>
> However, when I use 'catkin build' to build my workspace, I get the following error message:

So with `catkin_make`, `test_func()` is defined (and declared) in the same build context, while with `catkin_tools`, `test_func()` only exists within the context in which `function_maker` is processed.

This leads to `test_func()` being an unknown symbol in the latter case, hence the error message.

> How can I make this work with both build tools?

One approach could be to use the `CFG_EXTRAS` argument of the `catkin_package(..)` macro ([documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-package)).

This would allow you to *export* the function in such a way that its definition (and declaration) are imported into the build context of `function_user`, provided `function_user` properly `find_package(..)`s `function_maker`.

There are various Q&As on ROS Answers about this, see #q173947, #q173683, #q93266 and #q275318 for instance.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spencer Fishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40813/spencer-fishman/) on 2019-04-11**:
I will be testing this out today and will do so. Thank you for your help

**Comment by [Spencer Fishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40813/spencer-fishman/) on 2019-04-20**:
@gvdhoorn I thought I had this working, but went to `catkin build` today and I am running into an issue. The CFG_EXTRAS cmake file I created seems to not have access to some CMAKE variables. Specifically, the .cmake.in file thinks that ${function_maker_SOURCE_DIR} is an empty string. The reason I need this, is because "test_func" really uses some python scripts in ${function_maker_SOURCE_DIR}/src to generate headers from an XML file. Any idea how I can solve this?

**Comment by [Spencer Fishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40813/spencer-fishman/) on 2019-04-20**:
@gvdhoorn I ended up printing all defined cmake variables and found that instead of SOURCE_DIR, the extra cmake files defined the path as SOURCE_PREFIX. Was this documented? I am very unfamiliar with cmake, so maybe I should have known this.